# NativeScript WebView not loading html file

Tags: html, typescript, nativescript

Trying to load a local HTML file into webview in my native-script (typescript) application. It's not loading but shows an error.

```
<WebView src="~/assets/content.html" />
```

> The requested URL was not found on this server.

Comment: @AshishKamble This is for android right? My case here is on NativeScript.

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass the absolute URL or you can try the following.

```
import * as fs from "tns-core-modules/file-system";
public webViewSRC: string = encodeURI(`${fs.knownFolders.currentApp().path}/assets/content.html`);
```

and in your html

```
<WebView [src]="webViewSRC"></WebView>
```