# Nativescript App - load local HTML/JS/CSS in Webview

Tags: android, webview, nativescript

If I want to display a local html file in a Webview, how can I do it?

**Tried Solutions:**

- absolut path to the respective html I want to display in the webview as shown here:
  [Absolute path/ encodeURI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57703601/nativescript-webview-not-loading-html-file)

```
this.htmlPath = encodeURI(`${fs.knownFolders.currentApp().path}/monitordaten/webview/assets/graph.html`);
```

```
<Webview #myWebView [src]="htmlPath" ></Webview>
```

- editing webpack.config.js like this:
  this solution was mentioned here: [edit webpack.config.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53732871/load-local-html-javascript-css-inside-nativescript-app)

```
new CopyWebpackPlugin([
               { from: { glob: "monitrodaten/webview/assets/**"} },          <= Added this row
               { from: { glob: "fonts/**" } },
               { from: { glob: "**/*.jpg" } },
               ...
```

**both solutions lead to the following error:**
[image]
**Filestructure:**
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your path lacks of "app"

```
this.htmlPath = encodeURI(`${fs.knownFolders.currentApp().path}/app/monitordaten/webview/assets/graph.html`);
```

or

```
this.htmlPath = encodeURI(`~/app/monitordaten/webview/assets/graph.html`);
```

webpack config

```
{ from: { glob: "app/monitrodaten/webview/assets/**"} }
```